# OpenStreetMap add tag on map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am working on a webapp with openstreetmap and OpenLayers. What I have done is using JavaScript rendering  a line on map with some given points, like the screen capture below:

[image: capture1]

 Now what I would like to do is to have a tag displayed above the line, something like below:

[image]

 I am not sure how I can achieve this through JavaScript, and I couldn't find any useful reference document. Anyone have done this before please share some experience. 
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating opaque (or zero-width) points with styled labels. Here's my proposition based on [Labeled Features Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html). (I don't have possibility to test it right now, so watch out).

First: Create new vector layer (as styling settings might interfere with your current layer with line) styled with invisible points and some parameters:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Labeled points", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
        // should be invisible, if not, set opaque
        strokeWidth: 0,
        pointRadius: 0,
        // label may have \n linebreaks
        label : "${label}",
        fontColor: "${fontColor}",
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        labelAlign: "${align}",
        labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
        labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
        labelOutlineColor: "white",
        labelOutlineWidth: 3
        }})
    });
```

Second: Here's how you create feature with given parameters (the ${parameter}'s):

```
var newLabeledPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-101.04, 35.68);
var newLabeledFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(newLabeledPoint );
    newLabeledFeature .attributes = {
        label: "Line 1",
        fontColor: 'blue',
        align: "cm",
        // positive value moves the label to the right
        xOffset: 50,
        // negative value moves the label down
        yOffset: -15
    };
```

and finally: `vectorLayer.addFeatures([newLabeledFeature]);`.